# Immediate help required - Getting error 403 and 500 in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-500

I am working with Jmeter to do load testing. I created a simple login script using BlazeMeter. Then I imported the file into Jmeter.
Whenever I try to run the script, it fails. The problem I encounter here is that 2 of my https requests I receive a 403 and 500 response code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUels.png)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htKXr.png)

I added an HTTP Authorization Manager to try and solve this but it is not working. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this?
I tried adding post processors but couldn't make them work.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all `Template` value in the Regular Expression Extractor should be `$1$`
2. Also your regular expression itself looks kind of weird and I doubt it matches anything. You can check whether it generates the proper `${state}` variable by using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
3. In general [using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), it worth considering migrating to [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)

Comment: The ${state} value from the response it is extracted is correct. But when I check the same expression in the next responses, its giving partial value. Is there any way to correct it?